# Not able to call bean shell from Windows to remote host

Tags: beanshell

I am using bean shell to generate some data. It works fine on localhost (Linux), but when I invoke same script from remote host (Windows), my script is not loading and no error is also showing.

Comment: I don't suspect you will get a good answer to this question with so little details, no code, and no indication that you've done anything yourself to solve the problem. I'd recommend rewriting the question if you are serious.

Comment: I have tried to get the source code of the bean shell but not able to succeed. The way code has been implemented, I have very little room to make any changes as it is  a legacy code. It would be helpful if I can get source code. Also when I try to run the same application through eclipse, my script gets loaded, it fails only when run as an application. So I also suspect it to be a classpath issue but not sure.

Comment: All this information should be in the body of the question, not the comments.